# How do I get this lazy guy to move?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

There is a guy in Kaocho who sits near a lily pad and complains he is feeling tired and doesn't want to do anything. I need him to move so I can get to the djinn near by, but I have no idea what to do.

Amiti says his powers might help me, so I tried using the Insight Glass - this just showed me a picture of a bun type thing. I have no idea what to do with this information.

How can I get this lazy guy out of my way?

Comment: I request a screenshot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular guy wants a Kaocho dumpling:

[image: enter code here]

You can buy one in the food shop nearby:

(The video's in Italian, sadly for us that don't speak it - but you should be able to get the gist of it :)

If this shop is closed, try advancing the plot, since this shop will only be open:

> after Amiti joins the party.

Comment: Oh yay! Just proves a way to a man's heart is through his stomach. ;)